# Assign value by reference in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want to assign a value by reference.
For Example,

```
$scope.a = 10;
$scope.b = 20;

$scope.obj = {
   a1: $scope.a,
   b1: $scope.b
};
```

so now if I change the value of **$scope.a = 30**, then how to reflect it in **$scope.obj** (how can I get **obj.a1** as **30** value. It currently displays **10**)?

Answer (score 3):

Avoid putting primitive types into the scope, that doesn't work.

Start with

```
$scope.obj = { a: 10, b: 20};
```

Now you can modify `a` and `b` and two-way binding will work.

```
$scope.obj.a = 30;
...
```

See http://stsc3000.github.io/blog/2013/10/26/a-tale-of-frankenstein-and-binding-to-service-values-in-angular-dot-js/

Comment: Hey @Ian, But my question is that my $scope.a value changes dynamically so every time it is not feasible to assign it to $scope.obj.a1!!

Comment: Because your `$scope.a` is a primitive value it's not going to work, period.  Replace all your references to `$scope.a` with `$scope.obj.a` and it will work.  Why does it matter to you whether `a` is `$scope.a` or `$scope.obj.a`?